# Dúvida utilização do GIT

Tags: git

Minha dúvida se limita em saber se do jeito que fiz está correto a utilização do Git dentro da empresa em que trabalho.

Eu sei que o Git é descentralizado, porém como temos servidor de código local em rede eu optei por fazer da seguinte maneira que funciona mas quero saber se é correto:

No servidor onde todos os `devs` tem acesso criei um `git init --bare` para receber os `commits`.

Cada `dev` copiou o código fonte uma única vez para sua máquina e os `commits` são direcionados para o repositório `--bare` que configurei no servidor central.

Ou seja em cada máquina tive que dar um `git add remote origin /endereco/do/repositorio`, para quando der um `commit` e um `push` as alterações direcionarem o versionamento para esse diretório que configurei.

Então no fluxo normal antes de fazer qualquer alteração cada `dev` precisa dar um `pull` para estar sempre atualizado, realizar a alteração dar o `commit` e o `push`. E até ai está funcionando tudo mil maravilhas.

Gostaria de saber se dessa forma está correta.

Comment: Ao meu ver, está. pois acredito que é basicamente isso que acontece com o GitHub, por exemplo. Mas não entendo muito de Git, ainda está na minha lista para estudar mais a fundo.

Comment: quando vc diz que cada desenvolvedor "copiou" o código, vc quis dizer `git clone`? Porque dessa forma o passo `git add remote origin` não precisaria ter sido feito, eles já estariam automaticamente ligados ao repositório original.

Answer (score 0):

Está certa em partes.
 O modo de descentralização é o que é recomendado, mas com relação ao código poderia ser assim:

Você colocar uma aplicação no servidor que funcione como um github da vida, por exemplo o Gitlab ou o Gogs ( recomendo ) com ele você teria uma aplicação gerenciando os repositórios e poderia criar vários repositórios com vários branches em cada um.. Como o github.. Continuando a descentralização do código.. E na hora do deploy só precisa no servidor da aplicação clonar o endereço do código estável da aplicação onde está o código. Assim deixando cada aplicação no servidor com sua função.. Seja de repositório de código seja de hospedagem de aplicação ( espelhando o código estável ).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Marlysson, vou pesquisar a respeito do Gogs

Comment: Ok , qualquer coisa retorna com um feedback se deu certo.
Mais com o gogs ficará muito bem estruturado , é um ótimo sistema.